# Flask, get all list items from unordered list in form

Tags: jquery, python, html, flask

I'm making a page for adding recipes. When submitting a recipe, the user has to fill an unordered list with ingredients.

The HTML part looks like this

```
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type=text/javascript>
    $(function() {
      $('a#ingredient_input').bind('click', function() {
      $.getJSON('/_background', {
        ingredients: $('input[name="ingredients"]').val(),
      }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var node = document.createElement('li');
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(data.ingredients);
        node.appendChild(textnode);
        document.getElementById("ingr").appendChild(node);
      });
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<form action="/addrecipe/" method="POST">
     <h3>Ingredients</h3>
    <input type="text" name="ingredients">
    <a href="#" id=ingredient_input><button type="button">Add ingredient</button></a>
    <ul id="ingr" name="ingredients" value="{{request.form.ingredients}}"></ul>
   <input type="submit" Value="Submit new recipe">
</form>
```

In my `__init__.py` file I have a function `_background` which handle the addition of the ingredient to the `ul` and `addrecipe` which reads the request form. This looks like the following:

```
@app.route('/addrecipe/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def addrecipe():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.form
        result = request.form
        flash("Thanks for your recipe :)")
        flash(str(result))
        return redirect(url_for('newrecipe'))

@app.route('/_background/')
def background():
    try:
        i = request.args.get('ingredients', 0, type=str)
        return jsonify(ingredients=i)
    except Error:
        return str(e)
```

I would like to get the, let's say five ingredients the user enter. The number is variable, obviously. How can I do this? As it is now, I only get the last element in the `ul`...

Comment: You don't get the last element in the `ul`. You get the current value  of the `input`. Try to change add 3 ingredients then write "foobar" and submit without clicking "add ingredient", your form will receive "foobar". The `<form>` submits `<input>`s, and only `<input>`s (well, and similar elements such as textarea/select too). You have to rewrite your JS.

Comment: Ahh I see. You are completely right. Thanks for the help so far. Can you point me in the right direction? How would I go about getting back a list to Flask as I want?

Comment: I found the solution. I simply changed the list to a `textarea`, and instead of creating a `node` and then append the text, I just insert the text directly (with a `\n`) and problem solved. Once again, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Works. Alternatively, your JS could add a `<input type="hidden" …>` element to the form every time you add an ingredient.